# Display a bloc URL image in flutter

Tags: flutter, blob

I'm working on a flutter project and I have this blob URL : `blob:http://localhost:8401/5b85ac22-079a-410a-a05b-02fe09bda14a` which contain an image and I want to display it in my flutter project using `Image.asset("blob:http://localhost:8401/5b85ac22-079a-410a-a05b-02fe09bda14a")` but it gave me this error `urlopen error unknown url type: blob`. Is there a way to display a blob image. Any help is highly appreciated.