# Download image from blob url

Tags: flutter, image, file, url, blob

I need to download an image from a blob url.

I try using those solution, but none of them worked for me:

[Flutter WebView blob pdf download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865972/flutter-webview-blob-pdf-download)

https://github.com/guoguoguilai/flutter-webview-blob-download

[Display a bloc URL image in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437566/display-a-bloc-url-image-in-flutter))

```
final response = await get(
   Uri.parse(blob),
);
final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final File file = File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'image.png'))
..writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
```

Does anyone have a possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FileReader for getting bytes from blob
here is example:

```
final blob = Blob(); // ==> this is your html.blob
      final reader = html.FileReader()..readAsDataUrl(blob); //=> read data 
      await reader.onLoadEnd
          .firstWhere((element) => element.isTrusted ?? false);
      webBytes = UriData.parse(reader.result.toString()).contentAsBytes();
```